# hudson.FilePath : How to list subDirectories as well whole using excludes glob filter

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I am working on a Jenkins custom Plugin, where I need to list all valid FilePaths: sub-Directories and child files, excluding some temporary files like `.git,.npm,.cache etc`, the full list is included in below code sample:

```java
String excludes = "node_modules/**/*,**/node_modules/**/*,.git/**,.npm*/**,**/.npm*/**,**/.nvm*/**,**/cronus/**,**/.cache/**,**/npmtmp/**,**/.tmp/**";
FilePath[] validFileAndFolderPaths = workspace.list("**/*", excludes);
```

The above code is giving me all of the files in the `workspace` FilePath, but not the sub-directories.

There is a method for listing all sub-directories `hudson.FilePath#listDirectories`, but that doesn't support exclusion list.
Any help on how to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Do you want to recursively traverse and get all files and directories in the workspace?

Comment: That's correct @ycr. I would like to include both files and directories, except for the exclusion patten matched ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `hudson.FilePath#listDirectories` with a exclude/include patterns. Hence you will have to implement your own method to get the directories supporting Ant pattern matching. Here is a sample code.

**Dependency**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
  <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Java Code**

```java
private String [] getDirectories(String baseDir, String excludes) {

    DirSet ds = new DirSet();
    ds.setDir(new File(baseDir));
    for (String token : excludes.split(",")) {
        ds.createExclude().setName(token);
    }
    DirectoryScanner scanner = ds.getDirectoryScanner(new Project());
    String[] directories = scanner.getIncludedDirectories();

    return directories;
}
```

**Calling the method**

```java
String excludes = "node_modules/**/*,**/node_modules/**/*,.git/**,.npm*/**,**/.npm*/**,**/.nvm*/**,**/cronus/**,**/.cache/**,**/npmtmp/**,**/.tmp/**";
String dir = "/SOME/DIR";
String[] directories = getDirectories(dir, excludes);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @ycr. I have implemented it in a different way with CustomFileFilter, but your suggestion is the better way to address this.